# Is it OK to use for loop for step order in Apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have several functions (or transforms): func1, func2, func3, ...

and a dict that holds the functions

```py
FUNCS = {
    '1': func1,
    '2': func2,
    ...
}
```

What I'm thinking about is to pass a parameter `funcs`, that accepts a string of integers, and use `for` to loop through `funcs`, and execute the functions.

For example:

say I pass `funcs="1321"`, then the functions are executed as:

```py
with beam.Pipeline as p:
    lines = (
        p
        | "read file" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://some/inputData.txt')
    )
    for f in funcs: # 1321
        lines = lines | FUNCS[f](#some other params)
```

and the functions are executed in order: func1, func3, func2, func1.

Is there any difference compared with:

```py
with ...
    lines = ...
    lines = lines | func1 | func3 | func2 | func1
```

It's possible, I think; but is this even a good idea? Will there be any disadvantage about the parallel things of beam?

The true question is:

> Is the pipeline get built first, THEN get executed?

> Will the `for` loop and hard coded steps above end up with same pipeline? What effects does `for` loop have on efficiency and final result?

I'm using flex template of Google Dataflow btw.

Answer (score 3):

That's a smart question.

The short answer is: **Yes**, the pipeline is built first, and then executed.

The pipeline is only executed after you exit the `with` block.

Your `for` loop is completely fine.

Comment: let me know if you'd like me to dive deeper with the answer

Comment: So there's a long answer ;) Is there any official document that I can reference to?